# Changing DVD settings.

Tags: settings, dvd

it looks like I made a mistake on my settings. I want to install a program, but the computer thinks that I want to watch a video. Is it possible to change the settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this:

- Launch System Settings:

[image]

- Change the configuration

[image]

Source: http://ubuntuguide.net/ubuntu-12-04-actions-cd-dvd-blu-ray

Comment: Leopoldo Pla, I tried to do what you said and I am still having problems. I downloaded Kazam so that I could try and show you what I was seeing, but I don't know how to send the screenshot to this website. I noticed that you sent some screenshots, can you tell me how to do this so that I can help you see what is going on?

Comment: Leopoldo Pla, I don't know what I did differently, but MIDIsport Uno is now installed. I appreciate your help.